# Sorting strings without the use of awk or sed

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I have a homework in my class and part of it is to sort something a list of strings by their length.

We can not use `awk` or `sed`, only `bash`. Lets say I have something that looks like that:

```
ten
car 
something
plane 
stack
overflow
```

The end result of the sorting should be

```
something
overflow
stack
plane
ten 
car
```

That means the longer words on top and if they are the same size in alphabetical order.

That's what I've tried so far:

```
extSort(){
    total=$(cat $file| wc -w)
    count="$(cat $file | tr ' ' '\n' | tr -d '[:punct:]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2 -n)"
    while read line; do 
        if [ $(echo $line | wc -w) -eq 1 ]; then
            continue
        fi
    current=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f 1)
    percent=$(echo "$current/$total*100" | bc -l)
    round=$(echo "scale=2; $percent/1" | bc -l)"%%"
    printf "$line "$round"\n" done <<<"$input"
}
```

Comment: So you want us to do your homework?

Comment: I have done like 97% of it the problem is I can't figure this one out I have like a list that is 1500 lines long and did not find anything online so that little help should not be a problem :)

Comment: ok good so din't hesitate to post your atttempted code in question

Comment: Who is reopening this...

Comment: textSort(){

 total=$(cat $file| wc -w)
  count="$(cat $file | tr ' ' '\n' | tr -d '[:punct:]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2 -n)"
  while read line; do
   if [ $(echo $line | wc -w) -eq 1 ]; then
    continue
   fi
   current=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f 1)
   percent=$(echo "$current/$total*100" | bc -l)
   round=$(echo "scale=2; $percent/1" | bc -l)"%%"
   printf "$line "$round"\n"
  done <<<"$input"
}

Comment: It is hard to see but that is what I have done it gives you how many times a word was in the text and what % that is

Comment: Please don't post code in comments since it is, as you said, hard to read. Edit your question instead. I've did that for you this time.

Comment: thank you for that

Comment: `only bash`, then proceeds to use tons of non built in commands.

Comment: `while read word
do echo ${#word} $word
done < input | sort -n`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "ten
car 
something
plane 
stack
overflow" | while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do echo "${#line} ${line}"; done | sort -r -k 1,2 | cut -d ' ' -f 2
something
overflow
stack
plane
ten
car
$
```